# We get two different error reports for SharePoint surveys

Tags: sharepoint, survey

The nice response when a user tries to answer a survey twice is the message: "You are not allowed to respond again to this survey." But some of us are getting the standard "crash" screen for ASP.NET applications.

Is this a configuration item or something (we're on SP2007)?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what does the sharepoint logs show?

Comment: Not available to us. But I think I have a workaround. I've figured out how to use JavaScript to modify the behavior of the Respond To... button so that we offer our own notice of previous survey completion. Thanks for the suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting around this problem by completely substituting the default "Respond to..." button handler with this code, which replaces any attempt to re-take the survey with an alert informing the user he's done it already.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var myQueryOptions = "<QueryOptions />";
    //this was amazing: the value you need gets supplied by <UserID Type='Integer'/> (via Vadim Gremyachev)
    var myQuery = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer'/></Value></Eq></Where></Query>"; //find any instance of the current user
    var listPromise = $().SPServices({
        operation:  "GetListItems",
        listName: "{58ECDD94-8817-43A9-ACEC-42A1657E2F25}", //dev  Survey list
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: myQuery,
        CAMLQueryOptions: myQueryOptions
    });
    listPromise.done(function() {
        var iCount = $(listPromise.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ItemCount");
        if(iCount > 0) {
            $("[id*='_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RptControls_ctl00_diidIONewItem']").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("onclick", "");
                $(this).attr("href", "");
                $(this).on("click", function() {alert("You've already taken the survey!");});
            });
        }
        iCount++;
    });
    listPromise.fail(function() { alert("whoops");});
}); // $(document).ready()
```